# [MessageWebSocket]ConnectAsync Exception thrown: A connection with the server could not be established

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp

I have created client-server application. The client is created as UWP app. `Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket` is used to create connection with server. url : "ws://localhost:8097/devtools"

`ConnectAsync(new uri(<>))` api is used to connect with server.

The `ConnectAsync()` throws the following exception:

> $exception {"The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nA connection with the server could not be established\r\n"}
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException StackTrace " at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at ReactNative.Modules.WebSocket.WebSocketModule.d__8.MoveNext()" string*

Note: I have created console client application for the same. It works fine.

Comment: [Have you enabled local loopback for the UWP?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap4-loopbackaccessrules)

Comment: Currently  loop back is not enabled.  is that necessary to enable loop back?

Comment: Yes, for connecting to `localhost`

Comment: i checked with 'server name' instead of local host.  i got the same error.

Comment: You used the name of a remote server or did you use the name of the local machine?

Comment: i tried with name of the local machine

Comment: Then you need loop back enabled

Comment: k. thanks. enabled loop back and connection created for local machine. is there any thing to do for remote machine?

Comment: No you should just need the internet capability.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Does exclusively to UWP?

Meaning, would a Windows 8.1 Desktop app using WebSockets via C++/WinRT also need to set this loopback permission?

Comment: No, only UWP should need it.